# How do I get the maximum value for every group and rank with all other groups?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the max value for every team and rank the team ascending.
This is the dataframe:

```
TEAM   |  GROUP  |   SCORE  
1      |    A    |    5
1      |    B    |    5
1      |    C    |    5
2      |    D    |    6
2      |    A    |    6
3      |    D    |    5
3      |    A    |    5
```

No team should have the same rank so in case the score is similar who shows up first gets the first rank - others will adjust accordingly. So the output for this is:

```
TEAM   |  GROUP  |   SCORE   |  RANK
1      |    A    |    5      |   1
1      |    B    |    5      |   1
1      |    C    |    5      |   1
2      |    D    |    6      |   3
2      |    A    |    6      |   3
3      |    D    |    5      |   2
3      |    A    |    5      |   2
```

I'm not very familiar with some python syntax but here's what I have so far:

```
team = df.groupby(['TEAM'])

for x in team:
    df['Rank'] = x.groupby(['TEAM'])['SCORE'].max().rank()
```

Comment: What have you written so far. We need a specific issue to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I just added a chunk of code I was playing with.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below which uses sorting on score and team, then gets the changes and does a cumulative sum for rank:

```
s = df[['TEAM','SCORE']].sort_values(['SCORE','TEAM'])
df['RANK']  = s['TEAM'].ne(s['TEAM'].shift()).cumsum()
```

---

```
print(df)

   TEAM GROUP  SCORE  RANK
0     1     A      5     1
1     1     B      5     1
2     1     C      5     1
3     2     D      6     3
4     2     A      6     3
5     3     D      5     2
6     3     A      5     2
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma been quite busy lately :) was missing SO today :P

Comment: I believe its the other way around, SO was missing you today :)

Comment: Hi @anky it worked, but can you help me understand what line 2 of the code means? And what happens if I want to rank every team by desc score instead of asc?

Comment: @its.kcl for descending you can do `s = df[['TEAM','SCORE']].sort_values(['SCORE','TEAM'],ascending=False)` , this code is first sorting the value then checking if the next TEAM is different, if True, then assign a new rank else continue with same rank. Hope that helps

Comment: Hello! When I tried adding another team for some reason the ranking doesn't work anymore? It seems to only work for 3 teams or in this same condition.